# Piano music on “Sidewalls” (“Medianeras”) movie

Tags: soundtrack

I would like to know all the piano music played by Mariana's neighbour along with the movie.

One of them is Chopin's Etude Op. 10 No. 3 (Tristesse).

Could someone please help me identify the other ones?

Comment: How many different pieces are played? There are at least 2 Chopin pieces in that movie, but are those the only ones?

Comment: @Mast I think there are at least 4 musics, maybe 5. I don't if the other ones are also by chopin...